# SQL Count based off of two logs

Tags: sql

I have two logs: One log indicates every day I have the item in a warehouse, and the other indicates when that item has been purchased. How could I build a count that shows how many items that we have, that have been purchased, that we still possess per day?

Table1 - Report that shows the items we have, and the date it came in on the report

```
ID  | DateUploaded
123 | 1/1
123 | 1/2
124 | 1/2
123 | 1/3
124 | 1/3
123 | 1/4
124 | 1/4
124 | 1/5
```

Table2 - Log that shows when the item was purchased

```
123 | 1/2
124 | 1/3
```

Output:

```
1/1 | 0
1/2 | 1
1/3 | 2
1/4 | 2
1/5 | 1
```

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the output for `1/3` supposed to be `1`?
 Could you please explain why?

Comment: So 123 was purchased on 1/2, and 124 was purchased on 1/3, as can be seen on table2. On 1/3, both items are still in the warehouse, thus the count is 2. (124 came into the warehouse the same day it was purchased)

Comment: Based on table 1,  why is 1/1 not 1 and 1/2 not 2. Table 1 indicates they are in the warehouse on those days.   Also why does 123 show up on table 1 for 1/1 when it is not purchased until 1/2? same for 124, why does it show on table 1 on 1/2 if it wasn't purchased until 1/3?

Comment: 123 was moved into the warehouse on 1/1, as shown by table1, but was purchased on 1/2. The output is a report of what has been purchased, but still in the warehouse. 1/2 is 1 because while both 123 & 124 are in the warehouse, only 123 has been purchased. Table1 is when the item is in the warehouse each day, Table2 shows when items IN the warehouse have been purchased

Answer (score 0):

Found the query that works:

```
select t1.Date, count(*)
from table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.Date >= t2.Date
group by t1.Date
```